# Subtract largest multiple of 10

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, reactjs

I'm trying to set up animating in a list of items in React. I'm using Velocity for the animations, and using `react/addons`'s `TransitionGroup`. The easy part is using the index of the item in the list to "stagger" them in, but there's a problem when I load additional data from the server, and add them to the list: the index of the new items are from 20 to [x], so they wait (20 * 300ms) before the first one animates in. Given a number, say 23, is there an easy way to boil this down to 3 (remove 20 in this case, if the number were 55, boil it down to 5). This should be really basic, but I can't get my head around an elegant solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use modulus: %

23 % 10 = 3

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 var onesDigit = yourarray.length % 10;
```

Comment: I think this is a valid answer to the post. The question "Have you..." is rhetorical.